# TEMPLATE ERROR: No dictionary named: '' in: ['blog', 'skin', 'view'] when viewing blogger page

Tags: html, xml, templates, runtime-error, blogger

I'm creating a blogger template xml from scratch and I have an error on the page, when trying to show the page containing `<data:title/>` values and pages list in `<data:links/>` tags.

The generated html of the page contains `TEMPLATE ERROR: No dictionary named: '' in: ['blog', 'skin', 'view']` instead of inserting a proper value.

How to get data values in my custom template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be `<data:blog.title/>` not `<data:title/>`

data should be followed by a variable contained on that array `['blog', 'skin', 'view']`

Comment: `data:post.title` should do it but this will work inside the parts where `data:post` is used.


specifically, inside the `<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>` block 

`<data:blog.pageName/>` might also work if the page type is an article/item.